# NSPopover - Hide when focus lost? (clicked outside of popover)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopover

I'm using the `doubleClickAction` of a `NSTableView` to display a `NSPopover`. Something like this:

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [dataTableView clickedRow];
NSInteger selectedColumn = [dataTableView clickedColumn];


// If something was not selected, then we cannot display anything.
if(selectedRow < 0 || selectedColumn < 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid selected (%ld,%ld)", selectedRow, selectedColumn);
    return;
} // End of something was not selected

// Setup our view controller, make sure if there was already a popover displayed, that we kill that one off first. Finally create and display our new popover.
DataInspectorViewController * controller =
[[DataInspectorViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DataInspectorViewController"
                                              bundle: nil];

if(nil != dataPreviewPopover)
{
    [dataPreviewPopover close];
} // End of popover was already visible

dataPreviewPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[dataPreviewPopover setContentSize:NSMakeSize(400.0f, 400.0f)];
[dataPreviewPopover setContentViewController:controller];
[dataPreviewPopover setAnimates:YES];
[dataPreviewPopover showRelativeToRect: [dataTableView frameOfCellAtColumn: selectedColumn row: selectedRow]
                     ofView: dataTableView
              preferredEdge: NSMinYEdge];
```

Which works just fine. My popovers get created and removed on the cells that I double click on . The problem is, I want to the popover to go away if I click anywhere outside of it (like a single click on another cell). I have been looking around, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to do it.

This is something I would assume is built into a popover, (I'm fairly certain it was in the iOS `UIPopoverController` class) so I'm just wondering if im missing something simple.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to change the property behavior of your popover (in code or on interface builder) to:

```
popover.behavior = NSPopover.Behavior.transient;
```

> `NSPopover.Behavior.transient`
>   The system will close the popover when the user interacts with a user interface element outside the popover.

Read more about this in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover).

Comment: Is it possible to hide the popover when the user interacts with a  user interface outside the application?

Comment: In Objective-C: `self.myPopover.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorTransient;`

Answer (score 14):

the `.transient` flag doesn't work for me.

However I can make things work by the following:

1) Whenever I show my popover I make sure I activate the app
(my app is a menu-bar app, so this doesn't happen automatically)

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

2) When I click outside the app, then my app will be deactivated. I can detect this in the AppDelegate

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("resign active")
}
```

and act accordingly

Comment: This was of great help in Xamarin for MacOS using `public override void WillResignActive(NSNotification notification)`

Comment: Although it's not working when clicking on another menu-bar app (my app is also a menu-bar app). But works well outside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

After calling `show(relativeTo:of:preferredEdge:)` method,

Add below line

```
popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
```

And make sure you set

```
popover.behavior = .transient
```

Sorry, I've added solution in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

While `transient` worked for most cases, it was an issue when the user interacted with elements outside of the application, as the popover would hide but **not close**.

What finally ended working for me was:

```swift
popover.behavior = .semitransient
```

Now the popover closes when changing app, or interacting with any other element outside of the app. But will **not** close when interacting with a `NSMenu`, and maybe won't close either with other interactions.

Quoting from the documentation for [NSPopover.Behavior.semitransient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover/behavior/semitransient):

> The exact interactions that cause semi-transient popovers to close are not specified.

Similar to the documentation for [NSPopover.Behavior.transient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover/behavior/transient):

> The exact interactions that will cause transient popovers to close are not specified.